# Why my browser generated CSS works differently in Laravel?

Tags: css, laravel, vite

I am converting a html template into Laravel

The problem is the same CSS file works differently in Laravel version and when I check I came across that my browser is generating different CSS in Laravel version in compare to HTML version

I know it would sound weird  or confusing but below is the comparison CSS screenshot

HTML version

https://prnt.sc/-BPkQvskBp61

Laravel version

https://prnt.sc/-Pa9QPjvkWrW

Why is this happing? How can I resolve it?

Is it my fault or something else.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a Laravel thing... the stylesheet is coming from your user agent (aka browser).

Comment: So why the browser is treating the same thing  differently

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue. The `<!DOCTYPE html>` is missing from the HTML.

For more detail query kindly refer to Laracast discussion mentioned below

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/why-my-browser-generated-css-works-differently-in-laravel